# background image not displaying

Tags: php, html, css

can someone please tell me why the background image is not displaying in my php code.

```
#wrap-iframe{
    background-image: url(bg_01.gif); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;   
    border:0 none;
    min-width:760px;
    min-height: 700px;
}
```

this is the CSS i have. the div box is displayed flawlessly. the image url is correct. if i inlcude the image through the  tag, it shows up.

i was not this bad at CSS...:-(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that the image path must be relative to the stylesheet. If your stylesheet is in a different directory than the page, you must adjust the path in `url()` accordingly.

You can right click the DIV in Firefox and click "show background image". It will take you to the URL where firefox is looking for the image, and you can see whether it's correct or not.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using an "absolute" path. Start with a forward slash and describe the path from the HTML root forwards, i.e. `/images/bg_01.gif` would resolve to `http://yourdomain.com/images/bg_01.gif`

I always put quotes round the filename too, though they may not be 100% necessary:

```
background-image: url("/images/bg_01.gif");
```

Comment: As everywhere, the quotes are only necessary if you have spaces in path.

Comment: Yes, you're right BalusC. IMO it's one of those situations where it's better to just use quotes all the time in case you forget the special cases, same as fonts.